# What credentials to use with google app engine when cloning a repository?

Tags: git, google-app-engine, gcloud

I'm using Google Cloud SDK on Windows and when trying to clone a repository of one of my projects I get a pop window asking for credentials. I tried my Google account credentials and app specific credentials. I tried to reinstall the SDK and to reinitialize (gcloud init) many times. No credentials work and I keep getting this error message:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud source repos clone default
>
> Cloning into 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud
>   SDK\default'... Failed to erase credential: Element not found fatal:
>   Authentication failed for
>   'https://source.developers.google.com/p/XXXX/r/default/' ERROR:
>   (gcloud.source.repos.clone) Command '['git', 'clone',
>   'https://source.dev elopers.google.com/p/XXXXX/r/default',
>   'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cl oud SDK\default', '--config',
>   'credential.helper="gcloud.cmd"']' returned non-zero exit status 128

Answer (score 1):

There cloud be two issues related to this

1. `gcloud` might not be on the path. Are you able to do `where gcloud`? If not you can do `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin`
2. Running this command in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK`, generally you would not have permission to create any folders there, which clone command does. Try to switch to `C:\Users\YourUserName` and clone there.

If you still have issues please file it here https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/list

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestions, it didn't work. I hope that they will be able to help me @ https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/list

Comment: Issue report [link](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=431) for other users having the same issue.